# PHP array does not sort at all

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with sorting of an array.
$infoGroup is the result of a 'ldap_get_entries' call earlier. As I step through this array I put the result in the array $names.
Then I want to sort $names in alfabetical order, I have tried a number of different methods but to no avail. The array always stays in the same order it was constructed.

What have I missed?

```
foreach($infoGroup[$i]['member'] as $member) {
 //echo "<li>".$member;
 $go = stripos($member, "n");
 unset($names);
 $ai++;
 if ( $go == 1 ) {
  // extract member name from string
  $temp = substr($member, 0, stripos($member, ","));
  // Strip the CN= and change to lowercase for easy handling
  $temp = str_replace("cn=", "", $temp);                                
  $names[$ai] = ($temp);
 }
 if (natsort($names)){
  foreach ($names as $key => $val) {
   echo "<li>";
   echo "$key $val";
  }
 }
}
$ai = 0;
```

This is the result however I try to sort the $names array:

1. Henrik Lindbom
2. Klaus Rödel
3. Admin
4. Bernd Brandstetter
5. proxyuser
6. Patrik Löfström
7. Andreas Galic
8. Martin Stalder

Comment: I would avoid nesting the loops like this. Carry out one loop and populate a new array with results that match your conditions. Outside this loop, sort the new array and just print it out, can use echo "<pre>". $names ."</pre>"; to make it easier to read

Comment: It's probably exactly as Rob points out. Your sorting the array `$names` which always has just one element (as you unset it on every iteration).  Define `$names` outside the foreach loop as an empty array and remove the `unset`. Then you can sort and output the array after you filled it with all the members.

Comment: Ahh, of course... I have gone completely blind staring at this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.. a bit hard to explain, but the issue is because you are sorting your array inside that `foreach()` loop. Essentially, since you are creating the array element in the iteration of the first loop, the `natsort()` only has 1 element to sort and your nested `foreach()` loop is only outputting that 1 element, which is then unset() at the second and further iterations...

Extract that second `foreach()` that sorts and outputs and remove the `unset()` from the top of the first loop. This should output your desired results.

Something like this...

```
foreach($infoGroup[$i]['member'] as $member) {
 //echo "<li>".$member;
 $go = stripos($member, "n");
 $ai++;
 if ( $go == 1 ) {
  // extract member name from string
  $temp = substr($member, 0, stripos($member, ","));
  // Strip the CN= and change to lowercase for easy handling
  $temp = str_replace("cn=", "", $temp);                                
  $names[$ai] = ($temp);
 }
}

 if (natsort($names)){
  foreach ($names as $key => $val) {
   echo "<li>";
   echo "$key $val";
  }
 }
$ai = 0;
```